# Como funciona o comando git rebase?

Tags: git

O que acontece quando se faz um rebase na seguinte situação:

1. Branch master com 3 commits (A, B e C).
2. Após fazer o commit C, criei um novo branch com o nome design.
3. Fiz um commit (D) no branch design e voltei ao branch master.
4. Fiz um commit (E) no branch master.

Atualmente o meu histórico de commits é:

- master: A, B, C, E
- design: A, B, C, D

Após fazer o rebase no branch master, o histórico ficará da seguinte forma?

- master: A, B, C, D, E
- design: A, B, C, D

Se a resposta é sim, qual o objetivo de refazer o histórico quando uma das vantagens do Git é poder ver o histórico tal como ele é? Se posso manipular o histórico, então posso não ver o que realmente aconteceu.

Comment: o rebase costuma ser útil quando somente você mexe num determinado projeto, mas isso quando você não quer perder tempo fazendo merge, pois ele sobrescreve o histórico com as atualizações e ignora os conflitos, mantendo sua atualização como a mais recente e também despreza mudanças no meio do projeto feito por outras pessoas.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

O principal benefício do `rebase` é que começa uma abordagem muito mais "limpa".

Primeiro, elimina a intercalação desnecessário, compromisso esse exigido pelo `git merge`.

Em segundo lugar, rebasing também resulta num histórico de projeto perfeitamente linear onde pode acompanhar o inicio do percurso de todo o caminho do projeto, sem quaisquer problemas. Isto torna mais fácil para navegar no seu projeto com comandos como `git log`, `git bisect` e `gitk`.

Mas, há duas soluções de compromisso para esta história:

- Segurança e rastreabilidade: se não seguir a regra de ouro de `rebasing`, re-escrever a história do projeto pode ser potencialmente catastrófico para o seu fluxo de trabalho de colaboração. E, menos importante, rebasing perde o contexto fornecido por um `merge commit`, isto se não conseguir ver quando as alterações a montante foram incorporadas ao recurso.

A melhor forma de compreender todo o processo é por exemplo ler o seguinte Artigo:

[Merging vs Rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing)

Também deixo aqui imagens que resumem um bom exemplo de aplicação:

## Estado Inicial do Repositório

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Dev-B: Sincronização da Origem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Dev-B: rebase

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Dev-B: rebase final

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Dev-B: Sincronização Final para a Origem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 35):

Respondendo as suas perguntas.

> 1 - *Após fazer o rebase no branch master, o histórico ficará da
>   seguinte forma?*

Sim

> 2 - *Se a resposta é sim, qual o objetivo de refazer o histórico
>   quando uma das vantagens do GIT é poder ver o histórico tal como ele
>   é?*

O problema do `rebase` é que ele altera o histórico, assim como outros comandos do git (como os que levam o atributo `--hard`). Por isto ele é recomendado apenas em [casos bem específicos](http://qualidadegarantida.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/git-rebase-vs-merge-diferencas-e-qual.html). O Git não tem a premissa de proteger a qualquer custo o histórico de alterações mas de, por padrão, preservar isto.

Veja a seguir o que aconteceu em cada `commit`que fez.

Lembrando que `HEAD` é para onde o seu repositório está apontando no momento (pode ser uma `branch`, `tag` ou `commit` específico).

## Entendendo o cenário passo-a-passo

A seguir, vou detalhar o que ocorreu em cada passo que descreveu até o `rebase`.

Vamos lá:

> Branch master com 3 commits (A, B e C).

```
A<---B<---C
          |
          |
       |Master|
          |
         HEAD
```

Comando:

```
git checkout master
```

> Após fazer o commit C, criei um novo branch com o nome design.

```
        HEAD
          |
       |design|
          |
          |
A<---B<---C
          |
          |
       |Master|
```

Comando:

```
git commit -m "Commit C"
git checkout -b design      # cria a branch design a partir da branch atual (master)
```

> Fiz um commit (D) no branch design

```
                  HEAD
                    |
                |design|
                    |
                    |
                .---D
               /
A<---B<---C<--´
          |
          |
       |Master|
```

Comando:

```
git checkout design
git commit -m "Commit D"
```

> e voltei ao branch master.

```
                |design|
                    |
                    |
                .---D
               /
A<---B<---C<--´
          |
          |
       |Master|
          |
         HEAD
```

Comando:

```
git checkout master
```

> Fiz um commit (E) no branch master.

```
                |design|
                    |
                    |
                .---D
               /
A<---B<---C<--´-----E
                    |
                    |
                |Master|
                    |
                   HEAD
```

Comando:

```
git commit -m "Commit E"
```

E fazendo o `rebase`:

```
                |design|
                    |
                    |
                .---D<----E'
               /          |
A<---B<---C<--´           |
                       |Master|
```

Comando:

```
git checkout design
git rebase master
```

Como pode notar, com o `rebase` da master na branch `design`, os commits a mais (`E`) da `master` vão para o topo da branch `design`.

Assim, como pode notar ao final, os commits ficaram como você disse:

- master: A, B, C, D, E
- design: A, B, C, D

Comment: Uma das melhores explicações que li... Pra completar colocaria os comandos referentes aos commits e ao rebase no seu exemplo.

Comment: @DiegoBorges, done :)

Comment: @Dherik, Acho que esta errado o ultimo desenho. O "COMMIT E" vai pra BASE da branch "DESIGN". Por isto o nome "rebase". Ou seja, o COMMIT E fica atras do "COMMIT D". Sendo o "COMMIT D" o "HEAD."

Comment: @GBisconcini é isso mesmo, as branches também ao final apontam para o mesmo commit (creio que por isso ninguém notou o problema até agora). Vou corrigir depois. (fique à vontade para editar, se quiser)

Answer (score 14):

É exatamente isso que acontece. A principal vantagem do `rebase` em relação ao `merge` é que você terá um histórico bem mais limpo (e como realmente é) do que um projeto com merges, já que ele vai primeiro aplicar todos os commits do branch que está "rebaseando", para depois aplicar os commits do branch que está sendo "rebeseado". Entretando, `rebase` pode acarretar com algumas perdas de código que não acontecerão no `merge`, por isso é indicado que iniciantes não utilizem o `rebase`, mas sim o `merge`.

Além disso, a [regra de ouro do rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/the-golden-rule-of-rebasing) define quando fazer ou não um `rebase`. O `rebase` é aconselhado apenas para branches privados, ou seja, ele **deve ser evitado em branches públicos**, como o `master`, por exemplo. Isso evita que você bagunce branches públicos reorganizando os seus commits.

Em resumo, o `rebase` serve justamente pra manter um histórico mais limpo e linear, evitando commits "desnecessários" ocasionados por um eventual conflito de merges. Vale lembrar que algumas ferramentas funcionam somente com o `rebase`, como é o caso do [gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/), que cria uma linha de dependências dos commits enviados para com o branch principal (geralmente o `master`).