# O comando 'git push' não está funcionando após remover um commit

Tags: git, commit, gitlab

Precisei reverter um commit e localmente funciona bem. Agora quando vou dar PUSH pro meu repositório, ele me apresenta erro.

Minha tentativa

```
git fetch origin c6f1668e2fac57401a99a2184a47f0b58c15e403
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
git add .
git commit -m "revrt"
git push
```

ERRO

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/XXX'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Agora, se eu der PULL volta a uma versão que não quero.
O que eu faço?

Obrigadooo! :)

Answer (score 4):

Isso acontece porquê o *HEAD* do repositório local está atrás do remoto, isso siginifca que o *git* não vai deixar você enviar o novo conteúdo sem que você deixe claro que é isso o que deseja.

### Solução 1 (Recomendada)

Trabalhar em uma *branch* separada (ou em caso de já ter trabalhado na *branch* principal, use o [git stash](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ferramentas-do-Git-Fazendo-Stash) para separar as *branchs*). Supondo que está trabalhando na *branch* `develop` e a *branch* principal seja `master`, o fluxo seria esse:

Obter as últimas alterações de *master*:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Mudar para *branch* `develop` e fazer [merge](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ramifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Branching-no-Git-B%C3%A1sico-de-Branch-e-Merge) com *branch* principal:

```
git checkout develop
git merge master
```

Basicamente vai trazer as alterações de `master` para `develop`. Por fim fazer o commit da sua *branch*. Em caso de estar trabalhando em grupo, será necessário abrir um [merge request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/) para unir as alterações na principal.

### Solução 2

> Essa flag desabilita essas checagens e pode causar que o repositório remoto perca commits; use-o com cuidado.

porque vai sobrescrever forçadamente o último estado sem *merge*.

```
git push -f #irá forçar o push
```

### Solução 3

[Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81233/32827) é completa na terceira opção, `git rebase`.

Comment: Se tornou uma ótima base de conhecimento essa sua resposta