# Comando git push origin master retorna erro

Tags: git

```
$ git push origin master
To https://github.com/MarcusVSouza/cursoGitAlura.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/MarcusVSouza/cursoGitAlura.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse erro significa que a sua `branch` remota (`master`) possui atualizações de código mais recentes que a sua `branch` local. Tente o seguinte comando antes de fazer o `git` `push`:

```
git pull
```

e em seguida:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Olá Antônio, já fiz dessa forma git pull dps git push continua retornado o msm erro.

Comment: Entendi. Tente seguir essa resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272128/o-comando-git-push-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-funcionando-ap%C3%B3s-remover-um-commit

Comment: Usei o git push -f e funcionou, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Nunca force um push desse jeito, sempre após um pull verifique o status da sua branch, certamente outros arquivos foram foram inseridos no seu repositorio. Outra dica, nunca faça alterações na branch Master, use sempre uma branch secundária para isso, ao concluir a feature que estava em desenvolvimento basta fazer o merge.