# Como trabalhar com fork de um projeto?

Tags: git, github

Fiz o fork de um projeto, realizei as devidas alterações, realizei o push para meu repositório no Github e lá gerei um pull request para o repo do projeto original.

Passados alguns dias resolvi fazer uma nova contribuição, porém, o repositório original já sofreu varias atualizações. O que devo fazer?

Pensei em: adicionar os remote do repositório original e fazer um pull, isso esta correto? Cheguei a fazer um teste mas não parece ter puxado o conteúdo mais recente.

Seria isso mesmo?

Comment: Utilize [**git pull**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

Comment: Adiciona os remote e executa o git pull?

Comment: Se você está utilizando `git clone <repositório>` para clonar um repositório, não precisa adicionar informações adicionais, exceto se você tiver outros repositórios. No site http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html tem algumas dicas que pode ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

No seu clone local do seu repositório que foi feito o *fork*, você pode adicionar o repositório original do GitHub como `remote`. `remote`s são como apelidos para as URLs dos repositórios - por exemplo, `origin` é um deles. Então, você pode usar [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) para trazer todas as *branches* daquele repositório no *upstream*, e [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) para continuar a trabalhar na sua versão. A sequência de comandos seria mais ou menos assim:

```
# Adiciona o remote, chamando-o de "upstream":

git remote add upstream https://github.com/usuario/projeto.git

# Traz todas as branches daquele remote para remote-tracking branches,
# como por exemplo upstream/master:

git fetch upstream

# Garantindo que você esta na branch master:

git checkout master

# Rescreve sua master branch para que quaisquer commits seus que
# ainda não estão na upstream/master sejam replicados no topo daquela
# outra branch

git rebase upstream/master
```

---

Se você "rebaseou" sua *branch* para `upstream/master` talvez você precise forçar o *push* para que você consiga dar o *push* para o seu próprio repositório que foi feito o *fork* no GitHub.

```
git push -f #irá forçar o push
```

---

Referências

1. [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)
2. [How to GitHub: fork, branch, track, squash and pull request](https://www.gun.io/blog/how-to-github-fork-branch-and-pull-request)
3. [Como funciona o git rebase?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81221/como-funciona-o-git-rebase)