# Git Pull Request

Tags: git, github

Eu tenho uma branch em que eu tive que fazer varios commits para testar o CI/CD, e esta branch tem um PR aberta. Porem estes commits foram commits de teste e eu nao preciso do historico deles. Na maioria dos casos eu comentei algo do tipo: "testando CI/CD".

Como eu faco para resetar os commits desta branch mostrando no historico apenas o ultimo commit? Isto e possivel?

O que acontece por exemplo se eu deletar esta branch associada a esta PR tanto no origin, recriar local e submeter novamente com o pull?

Detalhe ja houveram comentarios nesta PR.

Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Não vejo muito sentido para ficar fazendo algo e apagando, o histórico é para saber mesmo o que fez e até voltar a tal ponto se necessário.

Comment: @Felipe se eu entendi, você tá querendo usar a opção Squash and Merge de um PR do GitHub. Dá uma lida e vê se isso atende sua necessidade mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o rebase iterativo para editar o histórico de commits do git. Vamos supor que os commits aos quais se refere sejam os cinco últimos, então você poderia fazer `git rebase -i HEAD~5`, onde 5 são os 5 commits que deseja alterar. Depois disso, o git abrirá o editor padrão com a lista de commits e um comentário logo abaixo com as opções disponíveis. Por padrão todos os commits vem marcados com `pick` (ou `p`), que significa usar o commits e assim não altera nada, mas você pode colocar `s` de `squash`, por exemplo, que vai unir aquele commit com o anterior e permitir que você edite a mensagem na sequência. Ou ainda, usar `f` de `fixup`, que vai unir o commit marado ao anterior, como o squash, mas descartará a mensagem. As outras opções estarão no comentário citado.

Comment: Resolvido com a sua sugestao. Muito obrigado pelo apoio. Sensacional!!!!

Comment: Complementando a resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81221/99718